# Adding nav menu name from plugin options dynamically

Tags: navigation

I have added my custom nav menu by this way.

```
function add_last_nav_item($items) {
    return $items .= '<li><a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#">More</a></li>';
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_last_nav_item');
```

Now I want to pull "More" from plugin options like

```
return $items .= '<li><a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#">$nav['menu_position']</a></li>';
```

where $nav is custom stored value

```
$nav['menu_position'];
```

Comment: Why do you add the tags "plugins" and "hacks", when it's about a navigation menu that will be displayed from a within a theme. And please edit your title so it reflects what you're actually asking about. And finally: What is your question?

Comment: I want to replace "More" with a variable.something  like $nav where $nav= echo $wptuts_options['label']

Comment: `'<li><a class="imagesDiv-link" href="#">'.$nav['menu_position'].'</a></li>'` ?.. Is your issue here limited how to concatenate string with variable?

Comment: Thank you @Rarst..Basically I am a lazy person and need things ready made...LOL